# Specific deep level size to load association in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Recently I created a project and in my models I have ManyToMany back references.

My model is like below:

```
@Entity
public class A {
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parents", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private Set<A> children = new HashSet<>();

   @ManyToMany
   @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
   @JoinTable(
       name = "link_a_recursion",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   )
   private Set<A> parents = new HashSet<>();

   //I removed the rest ( setter, getter and other fields )
}
```

When I fetch this model and I want to load children it throws StackOverFlowException error ( Recursive exception )
I want to know is there any way to say to hibernate just load one level of associate and don't go deep.

For clarify:

```
A.children[0].children[0].children should be null to stop recursion
```

I want to load the first children not all the children inside of the other children

**Edited:**

I add another entity:

```
@Entity
public class B {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b")
   private Set<A> entities = new HashSet<>();

   //setter, getter
}
```

and add below to A entity:

```
@ManyToOne
private B b;
```

then I changed below:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parents", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

to

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parents", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

and in my BService my findOne function is like below:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public B findOne(Long id) {
    B b = repository.findOne(id);
    for (A a: b.getEntities()) {
        a.getChildren().size();
    }
    return b;
}
```

but again I'm getting error :(

Answer (score 0):

Try lazy fetch instead

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parents", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but if you review my question I want to load first children not all the children in children, if I put Lazy loading, hibernate won't load the children at all @Tomas-Kralik

Comment: Hibernate should load the children when you try to access it when using lazy fetching. I thought that the problem might be that it tries to recursively access children in children in children etc. when using eager which might have caused the exception. But I might be mistaken

Comment: you are right, but when I turn it to Lazy and I want to load it in service layer ( getChildren().size() ), again I get the error because it tries to load all children of children too. I want to say stop doing that, just return me the first children

Comment: do you any idea? @Tomas-Kralik

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I don't think it is possible to initialize just one element of the collection. It simply fetches all related children when you access the attribute. But if you use lazy fetching, it should try to initialize just the "first level" and not anything more (like the collections in the children of children). Unless you access it of course. I don't know how the recursion occurs in this case, unfortunately

Comment: I change it to lazy and in my service layer I call children.size() for get the data but again it loads all the related children of that children I called its size() function. :( you know it's very easy in php framework just you should set recursive = (-1 or 0 or 1 or 2) @Tomas-Kralik

Comment: I don't think we understand each other now. Indeed, when you access the attribute, all elements in the set (children of the children) are initialized. I thought the problem was that Hibernate is trying to initialize all sets in all children recursively, despite the lazy load flag, which causes the system stack to overflow. When do you get the exception? Do you get it when you call children.size()?

Comment: Yes exactly,
I edited my question and I put exact example with my service class to clarify when I'm calling size() function.
Please review the edited section and see do you have any idea? @Tomas-Kralik